# AuthenticationState always returns null after successful log in

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, identity, principal

So i have this set up in another project, but when i have come to use exactly the same method, it always returns null

```
@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    private Task<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationState> authState { get; set; }
    private System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal principal;
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    private string NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }
    protected async override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        principal = (await authState).User;
        displayName = principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "display_name").Value;
    }
}
```

I can't figure out why this is the case, the startup class configure and configure services are pretty much identical. Can anyone point me in the direction on why this maybe the case?

Thanks

Comment: Which kind of authentication method are you using? After login success, have you ever add the claim to to HttpContext? Can you post the related code in the Login method, or post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 6):

I ran into AuthenticationState being null in a Blazor Service App. Check that `<CascadingAuthenticationState>`
is wrapped around the contents of the  App.razor file.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

[image]